# Using greater-than/less-than operator on enums without casting?

Tags: c#, enums, casting, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

I accidently wrote

```
if (myEnum1 < myEnum2)
{
   //do etc.
}
```

and I got no compiler errors.
Shouldn't I have to cast these enums to their underlying types first:

```
if ((int) myEnum1 < (int) myEnum2))
{
   //do etc.
}
```

Are these two snippets equivalent? My IDE, Jetbrains Rider, doesn't seem to think so. I can't jump to the `<` definitions so I assume it's a compiler thang'?

Comment: "My IDE, Jetbrains Rider, doesn't seem to think so" What do you mean?

Comment: I just mean my IntelliSense. Which in all other scenarios I've experienced, notifies the dev if casts are redundant. So this might be just an uncommon enough occurrence to have slipped through IntelliSense, or the snippets are not equivalent.

Comment: `Shouldn't I have to cast these enums to their underlying types first` Why do you think that?

Comment: Can you put your enum class code?

Comment: Can you normally jump to the definitions of built in operators? At least I can't on my version of Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: I thought that because I assumed C# would encourage devs to forget about the underlying values of enums and think about them abstractly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==` and `!=` are all defined for all enum types `E`:

```
bool operator ==(E x, E y);
bool operator !=(E x, E y);
bool operator <(E x, E y);
bool operator >(E x, E y);
bool operator <=(E x, E y);
bool operator >=(E x, E y);
```

This is specified in the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#enumeration-comparison-operators).

Their behaviour is described as follows:

> The result of evaluating `x op y`, where `x` and `y` are expressions of an enumeration type `E` with an underlying type `U`, and `op` is one of the comparison operators, is exactly the same as evaluating `((U)x) op ((U)y)`. In other words, the enumeration type comparison operators simply compare the underlying integral values of the two operands.

So your two code snippets would be the same if the enum has an underlying type of `int`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize `<, >, etc.` was defined for enum types.